# Is there any level of obfuscation which can "trick" instanceof?

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism, instanceof

I've been playing with this and so far I haven't been able to find any way to hide or trick `instanceof` into returning `false` by hiding its type through layers of obfuscation, but that doesn't mean it's not possible since I'm far from the most knowledgeable person about Java.  So I've come to ask the experts.

I've tried the following combinations, and in each case the `instanceof` operator is able to identify the true/base type of the object.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new TestObject();
        printType("Base Class", o);

        o = (TestSuperObject)(new TestObject());
        printType("Super Class", o);

        o = (TestInterface)(new TestObject());
        printType("Interface", o);

        o = (TestInterface)((TestSuperObject3)(new TestObject3()));
        printType("Interface on Super Class", o);

        o = (TestSuperObject3)((TestInterface)(new TestObject3()));
        printType("Super Class on Interface", o);
    }


    private static void printType(String testCase, Object o) {
        System.out.println(testCase);
        System.out.println("TestObject:" + (o instanceof TestObject));
        System.out.println("TestObject2:" + (o instanceof TestObject2));
        System.out.println("TestObject3:" + (o instanceof TestObject3));
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The classes are defined as...

```
public class TestObject extends TestSuperObject implements TestInterface
public class TestObject2 extends TestSuperObject implements TestInterface
public interface TestInterface
public class TestSuperObject
public class TestObject3 extends TestSuperObject3
public class TestSuperObject3 implements TestInterface
```

So basically, is there any way to hide this information or to somehow lose the type information?  I don't ask because I have a reason to do it, but rather would like to know and be wary of it in the future if it *is* possible.  Plus, I just find it interesting.

Comment: Not really. You can only "trick" your intuition by letting `instanceof` return a value that *looks* wrong. For example by letting `o` be of type `TestObject`, but loaded by a different classloader.

Comment: +1. But the way `instanceof` operator works; you don't stand a chance.

Comment: Note that all that casting only ever changes the type of the *variable* or *field*. It **never** changes the object pointed-to in any way. (Casting on primitive types is slightly different, but doesn't interact with `instanceof`).

Comment: How is casting primitive types different?

Comment: @Jeff: Casting 1234 to `byte` *does* return a different value. Casting it back to `int` *won't* result in 1234.

Comment: @Jeff this is not a bug, it's a feature! Really. It's a good thing, that basic language-features don't lie to you.

Comment: @Andy, I wasn't saying it was bad. :)  I was just curious if it could happen so that I could a) know the theory and b) avoid it in the future if it WAS possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to confuse yourself with `instanceof` but not the JVM.

- classes with the same name but in different packages are not the same. This means you can do

  ```
  // in one class
  ClassA classA = new ClassA(); // package1.ClassA
  another.test(classA);

  // calls in another class
  public void test(Object o) {
     if (o instanceof ClassA) // package2.ClassA => false
  ```
- using different class loaders the packages and `o.getClass().getName()` are the same, but as the class loaders are different `instanceof` return false.
- The object is `null` and `null instanceof ClassB` is always false, even though `null` can be assigned to any reference type.

Comment: Just one last question that came to mind: will it even see through generics?  Or do generics by their nature not have a type?

Comment: Generics are largely a compile time features and `instanceof` only checks the object referenced at runtime. For this reason you can't do `o instanceof T` if T is a generic.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically, is there any way to hide this information or to somehow lose the type information?

No it is not possible.

Each object has a real type, and Java's strong + static type system makes it impossible to alter the type of an object, or pretend that its actual type is different to what it is.

---

<sup>(It is hypothetically possible to drop into native code and subvert the Java type system, but the consequences of doing this are likely to be really bad ... crash-the-JVM bad.)</sup>

Comment: That's due to the fact that Java uses [strong typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_typing).

Answer (score 0):

You could run the code through an obfuscator. But this is basically a rename. `TestObject` may be renamed to e.g. `A`, but `instanceof A` still returns the correct result.

BTW: naming your classes *Object is a bad idea (in object oriented languages).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the OP really wants, but [this](http://ideone.com/5KtHs) may do it.

Basically I make the class private.  This means any `object instanceof Class` code will not compile (outside the scope of the private class).